# How to detect url input in chrome with a Batch Script

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, web

im currently making a URL Blocker for my Antivirus, and i need something that could detect url, or grab the url from the input of the user on their browser

Example: User inputted "google.com", then the script will detect, and grab the script, and the url will be stored on a variable

Im not currently working on it, as i dont really know how/where to start

Thanks in advance! :D <3

Comment: If you're just looking to grab user input, use `set /p`

Comment: If you want to get the input of the URL-line of the browser I will have to turn you down. After my knowledge this is not possible with only batch-script.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 is correct. A batch script does not interact with [tag:google-chrome]. A possible solution will be using extensions from Google Web Store, or alternatively you can write a tampermonkey script(basically a JS script)

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).